# How about a Limeriddle?

Tags: riddle, limerick

My start is bad electrically,
My end is something theoretically,
I’m bringing you here,
‘Cause you need to adhere,
Because we control you technically.

What am I?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are the:

> Electromagnetic Force

Comment: Incorrect, but good try

Answer (score 1):

I believe this make sense, even when the bad still confuse me

> a electro magnet

Comment: Good idea but incorrect